# Substitute Variables in web.config outside of appsettings, or connectionstring

Tags: octopus-deploy

The web.config in my `nupkg` file outputs the following:

```
<host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="#{Url.AccountService}"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
```

According to Octopus' documentation on [Substitute variables in files](https://octopus.com/docs/deployment-process/substitute-variables-in-files), the syntax above should be ok as long as I have the variable defined in my project. Which, I do.

[image]

I'm also deploying this package only to the `DEV` environment at this time.

[image]

Also, in the `Deploy Website` step, Under `Substitute Variables in Files` > I have `web.config` added to the list of files to perform the substitution on.

However, when the deployment goes through, octopus doesn't substitute this variable with the intended value. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your usage of the variable in the web.config looks correct. Your declaration of the variable in Octopus Deploy (Project Variables UI) looks correct. Listing 'web.config' in the section _Substitute Variables in Files_ is also sufficient (albeit in our systems we use `*.config`). One thing that stood out immediately is the usage of the dot in `Uri.AccountService`. Have you tried to remove the dot and see substitution occurs? We do not use a 'dot' in our variable names, so I am uncertain if this syntax is allowed. If that doesn't work, try using `*.config` and see observe the outcome.

Comment: No, unfortunately, that didn't work.

Comment: Is it possible the scope of your deployment is not `DEV` or `PROD-BLUE`?

Comment: It's `DEV`. I updated the question with the screenshot for your reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per our conversation above and things you have tried.
This is the only remaining idea I have for an answer for you:

The documentation [Substitute Variables in Files](https://octopus.com/docs/deployment-process/substitute-variables-in-files) states:

> You need to state the full path of the file, relative to the installation directory. So, if you need to replace variables on a file called app.config that is inside of a configfolder on the root of your package, you need to put config\app.configon the Target files field.

It is possible that Octopus Deploy cannot find the file that you are stating requires variable substitution. Everything else about your examples and code looks correct.

Comment: You were ABSOLUTELY right. Thank you so much for your help. I thought by adding *.config, I'm telling octopus to look into ALL of the config files.